# My sorting algorithm doesn't function due to unknown reason

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, for-loop, selection-sort

I'm trying to create a sorting algorithm, it contains a nested loop which compares each element of the array to all other elements in the array, and if an element is greater in value than any of its succeeding elements, they switch places with each other. But for some reason my program won't output anything and exits with code 0, i.e. success.

Following is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void sortAlgo(int *a, int n){
    int tmp;
    for (int i=0; i<=n-1; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<=n; j++){ //O(n^2)
            if(a[i]>a[j]){
                //LHS variable assumes RHS quantity
                tmp=a[i]; //a[i] value stored in temp variable
                a[i]=a[j]; //shifts a[j] value to a[i]
                a[j]=tmp; //a[j] takes value of a[i]
            }
        }
    }
    for(int x=0; x<=n; x++){
                cout<<a[x]<<" ";
            }
}

int main(){
    int arr[10]={1,2,3,5,23,12,4};
    sortAlgo(arr, 7);
}
```

I am using VS Code.

Comment: Is there a reason you're writing your own sort?

Comment: This is the second recent question about bubble sort that got the algorithm wrong. It's the simplest sort in existence, and it's obvious even from its Wikipedia page that this is using the wrong loop condition. No insult to OP, but if I ever meet the person writing these tutorials I'm going to have some fairly direct feedback for them.

Comment: Any time you're using `<=` in a loop condition you are probably going out of bounds. Like `for(int x; x<=n; x++)` and `for(int j=i+1; j<=n; j++)`. `for (int i=0; i<=n-1; i++)` could be rewritten as `for (int i=0; i < n; i++)`.

Comment: Anyway, to the point: run it in a debugger. Step through your code and see what is happening. Add print statements if you must. And enable all your compiler warnings.

Comment: In `for(int x; x<=n; x++)`, what's the initial value of `x`? It's undefined, so it's random garbage at runtime (likely _not_ zero), so the code doesn't output anything.

Comment: I'm just trying to more proficient in my C++ skills, what better way would there be than to write sort algorithms, it would be nice if I could get my programs to function the way I desire and would help me progress my skill :)

Comment: There are *lots* of ways.  I'd start by learning about the STL.

Comment: I've done the initialisation `int x=0`, still not fixed. Some of you guys have said it's the wrong loop for bubble, while I agree and am making changes, this isn't exactly that, just a sort inspired from bubble, would be valuable if someone could teach how to get my base idea here to work. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the bubble sort algorithm You are trying to implement the selection sort algorithm with redundant swaps.

These for loops

```
for(int j=i+1; j<=n; j++){ //O(n^2)
```

and

```
for(int x; x<=n; x++){
```

have invalid conditions that in general can result in undefined behavior if the passed array will have exactly `n` elements because the expression `a[n]` will access memory beyond the array..

Moreover in the second for loop the variable `x` was not initialized that again invokes undefined behavior.

Pay attention to that instead of to swap "manually" two elements

```
tmp=a[i]; //a[i] value stored in temp variable
a[i]=a[j]; //shifts a[j] value to a[i]
a[j]=tmp; //a[j] takes value of a[i]
```

you could use standard C++ function `std::swap` declared in the header `<utility>`.

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry for the fundamental errors I've made in both asking and implementation. This place schools you quite occasionally and I guess that's how one learns.